# Create table fail

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am creating a table in the database, but there is an error.
How to fix this question?

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
    categoryID int NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    categoryName varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
    );
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'categoryName'

Comment: What could you possibly mean by `NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL`?  That doesn't make sense.  Either `NULL` values are allowed or they are not allowed.

Comment: ... and default value for autoincremented column makes no sense too.

Answer (score 1):

You cant set NULL by default categoryName, you just set it to be NOT NULL.
Must change one of the two declarations.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have condition NOT NULL and  DEFAULT NULL you should choose one.
Second, you can't have ID DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULLif you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead